# Overwrite levels of factor columns in one dataframe using another

Tags: r, factors, levels

I have 2 data frames with multiple factor columns. One is the base data frame and the other is the final data frame. I want to update the levels of the base data frame using the final data frame.

Consider this example:

```
base <- data.frame(product=c("Business Call", "Business Transactional", 
                             "Monthly Non-Compounding and Standard Non-Compounding",
                             "OCR based Call", "Offsale Call", "Offsale Savings",
                             "Offsale Transactional", "Out of Scope","Personal Call"))
base$product <- as.factor(base$product)

final <- data.frame(product=c("Business Call", "Business Transactional", 
                              "Monthly Standard Non-Compounding", "OCR based Call", 
                              "Offsale Call", "Offsale Savings","Offsale Transactional", 
                              "Out of Scope","Personal Call", "You Money")) 
final$product <- as.factor(final$product)
```

What I would now want is for the final data base to have the same levels as base and remove the levels which do not exist at all like "You Money". Whereas "Monthly Standard Non-Compounding" to be fuzzy matched

Eg:

```
levels(base$var1) <- "a" "b" "c"
levels(final$var1) <- "Aa" "Bb" "Cc"
```

Is there a way to overwrite the levels in base data using the final data using some kind of fuzzy match?

Like I want the final levels for both data to be the same. i.e.

```
levels(base$var1) <- "Aa" "Bb" "Cc"
levels(final$var1) <- "Aa" "Bb" "Cc"
```

Comment: what do you mean fuzzy match?

Comment: if the order of labels are kept between two data frames, perhaps we could simply `base$var1 = factor(base$var1, levels(base$var1), levels(final$var1))`

Comment: I have added a working example! @OmG

Comment: @Quar I have added a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could build our own `fuzzyMatcher`.

First, we'll need kinda vectorized `agrep` function,

```
agrepv <- function(x, y) all(as.logical(sapply(x, agrep, y)))
```

on which we build our `fuzzyMatcher`.

```
fuzzyMatcher <-  function(from, to) { 
  mc <- mapply(function(y) 
    which(mapply(function(x) agrepv(y, x), Map(levels, to))), 
    Map(levels, from))
  return(Map(function(x, y) `levels<-`(x, y), base, 
             Map(levels, from)[mc]))
}
```

`final` labels applied on `base` labels (*note,* that I've shifted columns to make it a little more sophisticated):

```
base[] <- fuzzyMatcher(final1, base1)
#    X1 X2
# 1  Aa Xx
# 2  Aa Xx
# 3  Aa Yy
# 4  Aa Yy
# 5  Bb Yy
# 6  Bb Zz
# 7  Bb Zz
# 8  Aa Xx
# 9  Cc Xx
# 10 Cc Zz
```

### Update

Based on the new provided data above it'll make sense to use another vectorized `agrepv2()`, which, used with `outer()`, enables us to apply `agrep` on all combinations of the levels of both vectors. Hereafter `colSums` that equal zero give us non-matching levels and `which.max` the matching levels of the target data frame `final`. We can use these two resulting vectors on the one hand to delete unused rows of `final`, on the other hand to subset the desired levels of the `base` data frame in order to rebuild the factor column.

```
# add to mimic other columns in data frame
base$x <- seq(nrow(base))
final$x <- seq(nrow(final))

# some abbrevations for convenience
p1 <- levels(base$product)
p2 <- levels(final$product)

# agrep
AGREPV2 <- Vectorize(function(x, y, ...) agrep(p2[x], p1[y]))  # new vectorized agrep 
out <- t(outer(seq(p2), seq(p1), agrepv2, max.distance=0.9))  # apply `agrepv2`
del.col <- grep(0, colSums(apply(out, 2, lengths))) # find negative matches
lvl <- unlist(apply(out, 2, which.max))  # find positive matches
lvl <- as.character(p2[lvl])  # get the labels

# delete "non-existing" rows and re-generate factor with new labels
transform(final[-del.col, ], product=factor(product, labels=lvl))
#                  product x
# 1          Business Call 1
# 2 Business Transactional 2
# 4         OCR based Call 4
# 5           Offsale Call 5
# 6        Offsale Savings 6
# 7  Offsale Transactional 7
# 8           Out of Scope 8
# 9          Personal Call 9
```

#### Data

```
base1 <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

final1 <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Xx", "Yy", "Zz"), class = "factor"), 
    X2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the order isn't the same. You think there is a way? Also, when the levels aren't equal

Comment: @BruceWayne It would be great if you could design a self-contained [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038).

Comment: Sure! Let me try

Comment: I have updated with a new example which is exactly what I would like to replicate

Comment: @BruceWayne Great, see update. I didn't know what you want to do with the "non existing levels" since they do exist. I decided to delete the rows. Another way could be to set them to `NA` or name them `"unmatched"`?

Comment: But you're missing the product "Monthly Standard Non-Compounding" which should occur as a fuzzy match @jay.sf

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry you wrote "remove the levels which do not exist at all like "You Money" and "Monthly Standard Non-Compounding"". I'm sure you're able to fine-tune it to your needs.

Comment: @BruceWayne you're welcome, quite interesting question!